# How do I access vc_map() internal values to create custom markup for WPBakery interface?

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer, wpbakery

A similar question has been asked here, without any viable responses: [Visual Composer custom markup for custom shortcode (vc_map)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980890/visual-composer-custom-markup-for-custom-shortcode-vc-map)

and here: [Visual Composer custom shortcode template - custom_markup display user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745605/visual-composer-custom-shortcode-template-custom-markup-display-user-input)

I am trying to create custom markup within the WPBakery interface.

I can add custom markup no problem by doing:

```
$markup = 'test'; 
vc_map( array(
   "name" => __("MyShortcode"),
   "base" => "myshortcode",
   "category" => __('Content'),
   "custom_markup" => $markup, // @TODO how do we access shortcode's attributes here to display in bakery grid
   "params" => $params
) );
```

This will output "test" in the WPBakery grid which is good, but how do I access vc_map() internal values to display?

For instance I have "post types" as a field for this shortcode. If someone selects "page" post type for example, I would like to display those posts within the WPBakery grid. What I cannot figure out is how to get the values that the user selected to display.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've searched endlessly on this one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44462263/how-to-use-custom-markup-parameter-in-visual-composer-vc-map

Answer (score -2):

I found a solution. By extending the class WPBakeryShortCode, you could change the contentAdmin output :

```
// Extend Class WPBakeryShortCodesContainer
if (class_exists('WPBakeryShortCode')) {
class WPBakeryShortCode_Custom_Element extends WPBakeryShortCode {
    /**
     * @param $atts
     * @param $content
     *
     * @return string
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function contentAdmin( $atts, $content = null ) {
        $output = $custom_markup = $width = $el_position = '';
        if ( null !== $content ) {
            $content = wpautop( stripslashes( $content ) );
        }

        $shortcode_attributes = array( 'width' => '1/1' );
        $atts = vc_map_get_attributes( $this->getShortcode(), $atts ) + $shortcode_attributes;
        $this->atts = $atts;
        $elem = $this->getElementHolder( $width );
        if ( isset( $this->settings['custom_markup'] ) && '' !== $this->settings['custom_markup'] ) {
            $markup = $this->settings['custom_markup'];
            $elem = str_ireplace( '%wpb_element_content%', $this->customMarkup( $markup, $content ), $elem );
            $output .= $elem;
        } else {
            $inner = $this->outputTitle( $this->settings['name'] );
            $inner .= $this->paramsHtmlHolders( $atts );
            $elem = str_ireplace( '%wpb_element_content%', $inner, $elem );
            $output .= $elem;
        }

        return $output;
    }
}
}
```

I follow this Git example to create my custom elements : https://gist.github.com/Webcreations907/ff0b068c5c364f63e45d